# `rpm -qa` vs `yum list installed`: Why certain packages can be found with `rpm -qa` only?

Tags: centos, python, yum, rpm

I've `Python 2.7.5` installed in CentOS and wondering why I can find this using `rpm -qa` but not `yum list installed` command?

```
[root@CentOS7 centos]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@CentOS7 centos]# 

[root@CentOS7 centos]# rpm -qa | grep python-2.7.5
python-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64
[root@CentOS7 centos]#

[root@CentOS7 centos]# yum list installed | grep python-2.7.5
[root@CentOS7 centos]#
```

**My reference:**

http://www.linuxnix.com/list-installed-packages-and-their-details-in-redhatcentosfedore/

Comment: The command `rpm -qa` queries the `/var/lib/rpm` database which retrieves the package installed. `yum` will show the package name, version and the repository. The equivalent of `rpm` would be `rpm -qa --qf '%{name}.%{arch}\n'`  Hope this is useful

Comment: To add on top of that. `yum list installed | grep python*` would have matched the name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `grep` from `yum list installed` you will not get the same format as you would with `rpm -qa`

See :

```
[root@user1 ~]# yum list installed | grep 2.7.5
python.x86_64                          2.7.5-58.el7                    @base    
python-libs.x86_64                     2.7.5-58.el7                    @base  


[root@user1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep 2.7.5
python-libs-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64
python-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64
```

`yum list installed` shows you the package name, version number and the repository nickname it was downloaded from in 3 different columns.

So for `yum list installed` you want to `grep` **only** the package name or version number. You cannot `grep` them together like you would with `rpm -qa`.

```
[root@user1 ~]# yum list installed | grep python.x86_64
audit-libs-python.x86_64               2.7.6-3.el7                     @base    
dbus-python.x86_64                     1.1.1-9.el7                     installed
libselinux-python.x86_64               2.5-11.el7                      @base    
libsemanage-python.x86_64              2.5-8.el7                       @base    
libxml2-python.x86_64                  2.9.1-6.el7_2.3                 installed
newt-python.x86_64                     0.52.15-4.el7                   installed
policycoreutils-python.x86_64          2.5-17.1.el7                    @base    
python.x86_64                          2.7.5-58.el7                    @base    
rpm-python.x86_64                      4.11.3-25.el7                   @base
```